# Regex pattern failing valid strings using Mongo json schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb

I am trying to add a schema to one of my Mongo DB collections. One field should be guarded by the following regex pattern:

```
^rgba[(][0-9]+, [0-9]+, [0-9]+, (0([.][0-9]+)?|1([.]0+)?)[)]$
```

This regex expression successfully passes correctly structured strings such as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` using Node.js. Unfortunately, when using the same regex in my json schema it seems to not match any strings. The schema for the specific field:

```js
textColor: {
    bsonType: "string",
    pattern: "^rgba[(][0-9]+, [0-9]+, [0-9]+, (0([.][0-9]+)?|1([.]0+)?)[)]$"
}
```

Is there anything inside of the regex string that should be escaped to make it work? How can I rewrite this to make it work?

Comment: Try to add a ```/``` at the beginning and end of the pattern and see if that works

Comment: Works for me: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/Pf8RsaCs

Comment: Maybe this pattern works? `"^rgba\\((\\d+, *){3}(0(\\.\\d+)?|1(\\.0+)?)\\)$"`, which is regex `/^rgba\((\d+, *){3}(0(\.\d+)?|1(\.0+)?)\)$/`

Comment: @BramVanbilsen when you write "it does not match any strings" – does it mean that mongo rejects all (including valid) inputs or never rejects invalid inputs? Have you set the validator for your collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was unrelated to the regex expression. The update for the schema was not added properly to the collection. Which was an error on my side of things and unrelated to MongoDB at all. The regex did actually end up working.

Comment: In that case the question is "not reproducible or was caused by a typo" and should be closed. The answer does not explain _what_ the reason was and _how_ it was fixed. Future visitors with similar problems will not get anything out of this question + answer.